# curl post php 403 forbidden

Tags: php, curl, parameters, request, httpforbiddenhandler

i'm tring to post my data using POST methode and curl excute , but the result is

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>  You do not have permission to
>   view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

```
$request='';
$url='https://app.highwire.com/api/auth';
$header=array('mydata');
$con = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
    curl_setopt($con, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6');
    $res = curl_exec($con);
    curl_close($con);
```

Comment: Did you checked the credentials?

Comment: yesss I have the $header , and for the $request it's empty . I'm trying to test in this link chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn/index.html#response and it works , but from my web site I have this problem.